# Find all file types for Ubuntu font

Tags: fonts

I need all file types for Ubuntu font (EOT, TTF, EOT, WOFF) for bold, light and regular. I've searched all over the internet, but I have found only TTF download link.

I tried to find them, but there is tons of information about a method for the page to load any type of font, using Google's server, but I need the files to be on my server.

How can I find them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the type of fonts can be found on this github repo:
https://github.com/earaujoassis/ubuntu-fontface

Comment: If you additionally need WOFF2 you can find it here: http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/ubuntu/v7/zvCUQcxqeoKhyOlbifSAaevvDin1pK8aKteLpeZ5c0A.woff2 or download all formats at http://www.localfont.com/

Comment: Wow, didn't know about localfont.com. It seems a really good ideea. Thanks for sharing it!